# Why is QGIS 2.8.1 crashing when enabling Grass Plugin?

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-plugins

I am running Linux Mint 13 "Maya" (Ubuntu 12.04 Precise). I installed 
Grass via the software center. Than I installed Qgis 2.81 following this procedure:

```
Add the lines for one of the repositories to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

deb     http://qgis.org/debian precise main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian precise main

After that type:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

QGIS runs fine, but when enabling the Grass plugin it crashes.

Comment: QGIS doesn't run fine if it crashes when GRASS Plugin is enabled. Your Linux Mint is very old (current version is 17.1 Rebecca). Furthermore, You have the QGIS repos of an Ubuntu version (12.04) no longer supported. Current version of Ubuntu is 15.04 and it will have only 9 month of support. This is the problem of distros derived from Debian unstable and incapable to upgrade adequately.

Comment: Got the message. Upgradet my Linux Mint to the newest LTS and installed QGIS as well as GRASS GIS 7. It seems to work.